# Найти китайские иероглифы в тексте

Tags: delphi

Кто подскажет как можно узнать, есть ли в тексте иероглифы?

Comment: @ms301 Какая версия Delphi? Что подразумевается под иероглифом? Символ который в UTF-16 не влезает в один байт это иероглиф?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode

Comment: под иероглифом я подразумеваю китайский иероглиф, например "湖"

Comment: В какой кодировке Ваш текст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В **Delphi 7** с поиском, подобного рода символов, были сложности ввиду ограничений типа string AnsiString и используемой по умолчанию кодировки в самой Delphi 7.

Если речь идет о расширенных кодировках символов,  следует уточнить, что поддержка такого рода кодовых таблиц (**UTF-16**), появилась в более новых версиях **Delphi (2009 и новее)**
Для работы с символами **UTF-16**, нужно использовать  и специальные типы данных, например:

Тип **WideChar** **#0..#65535** (для работы с одним символом) имеет размерность 16 бит, обеспечивая поддержку многобайтовых наборов Интернациональных символов типа Китайского, который содержит большое число символов в своём словаре.

А для работы с текстовой строкой расширенных кодировок, можно использовать  **WideString**

[Диапазон иегроглифов в UTF-16](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B,_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5)

Путем перебора символов необходимого вам диапазона, можно определить, является ли символ в строке иероглифом.